# Rake cannot load such file Unit Test

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rake, rakefile

I'm want to automate testing with rake. 
When I run this from the command prompt, in the home directory, my tests run fine.

```
ruby -I  lib/radar_mon/ tests/radar_mon/test_geoname.rb
```

my Rakefile looks like this:

```
task default: %w[test]

task :test do
   ruby "tests/radar_mon/test_geoname.rb"
end
```

my test file test_geoname.rb looks like this

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'geoname'

class TestGeoname < Test::Unit::TestCase
   def test_first
      g = Geoname.new( [0.0,0.0] )
      assert_equal( [0.0,0.0], g.location)
   end
end
```

Library structure is like this

```
home/lib/radar_mon/geoname.rb

home/tests/radar_mon/test_geoname.rb

home/Rakefile
```

How can I configure my rake file to run the test? I'm not supposed to change the require statement in the test file.

```
/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.10/bin/ruby tests/radar_mon/test_geoname.rb
tests/radar_mon/test_geoname.rb:2:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /home/pi/Documents/HurricaneTracker/tests/radar_mon/geoname (LoadError)
        from tests/radar_mon/test_geoname.rb:2:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
```

Not sure if it matters but I'm using rvm.

Comment: Edit your post and paste in the actual error message.

Comment: Did you try adding the requires in the Rakefile ?

Comment: no I did not try that

Answer (score 1):

What about trying to add something like this to the top of your Rakefile, you might need to modify this to only require files needed by your rake task.

```
Dir[File.join(__dir__, "/**/*.rb")].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

More specifically for your case this would work:

```
my_files = FileList['home/lib/radar_mon/*.rb', 'home/tests/radar_mon.*rb']

my_files.each do |file|
  require file
end

task default: %w[test]

task :test do
  ruby "tests/radar_mon/test_geoname.rb"
end
```

This works because Rake is handling the requires in this case recursively.  `FileList` is provided by `rake`.

For more info you might wanna refer to the [rake gem documentation](http://github.com/ruby/rake)
and perhaps http://www.virtuouscode.com/2014/04/24/rake-part-4-pathmap/

Comment: That second part doesn't work, not sure what the first part does.

Comment: Yeah I realized that and removed it. But the first part or a variation should work

Comment: Wow, that fixed it. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Updated my answer but basically `require` will load a ruby file only if it has not already been loaded.  Doing the require's inside the `Rakefile` should required any libraries need by your task.